# How do I index for a mysql query using or with multiple columns

Tags: mysql

My Query:

```
SELECT * FROM privatemessages69 
WHERE sender='19' OR recipient='19' 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `privatemessages69` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `recipient` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `readstatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `messagetype` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `msgpanel` (`sender`,`recipient`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Explain:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM privatemessages69 WHERE sender='19' OR recipient='19' ORDER BY id DESC;
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | privatemessages69 | index | msgpanel      | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 50191 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone tell me the correct way of indexing this table for that query? If I remove the order by, type goes to ALL.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having one index on `sender` and one on `recipient` should be enough for such a query:

```
CREATE INDEX ind_sender
    ON privatemessages69 (sender) ;

CREATE INDEX ind_recipient 
    ON privatemessages69 (recipient) ;
```

And I don't think it's going to be faster if you write it using `UNION`.

---

You can also try adding these two indexes (and removing the above ones):

```
CREATE INDEX ind_sender_2
    ON privatemessages69 (sender, id) ;

CREATE INDEX ind_recipient_2
    ON privatemessages69 (recipient, id) ;
```

I can't test now but it may get rid of the filesort.

---

You can still edit your question and add at the end:

- Time with ORDER BY: (3-4 seconds as
  you say)
- Number of total rows in the
  table:
- Number of rows with
  `recipient=19`:
- Number of rows with
  `sender=19`:
- Number of rows the query
  returns:

Some tests I did yesterday with about 300 thousand total rows showed the query running in less than a second. The slowness maybe due to configuration settings of MySQL.

Also: Does the query takes 3-4 seconds whatever you put (instead of `19`)?

Comment: This definitely seems to be the fastest way of doing it. I guess the only real problem i'm having now is ORDER BY slowing down the query. Do you know of a good solution for speeding that up? (Should I ask this as a new question? New Here) Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't index the table for that query, but here is an another one that will run fast, if you put 2 distinct indexes on `sender` and `recipient`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM privatemessages69 WHERE sender=19
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM privatemessages69 WHERE recipient=19
) t
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: Any reference to why that is?

Comment: @Kevin Peno: Mysql cannot make use of an index spanning 2 two columns, if both columns are combined using `OR`. Have a look at the mysql documentation explaining index usage (last example box): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: @soulmerge, I guess I always thought that `OR` in `WHERE` [loosely] implied `UNION`. Thanks for the refresher.

Comment: @soulmerge, in the box prior to the one you mentioned I see `WHERE index=1 OR A=10 AND index=2`, translated to `index=1 OR index=2`, thus, as I understand it, `OR` would work so long as you had multiple indexes (per my answer). Am I interputing this wrong?

Comment: @soulmerge, **if** you add a **seperate** index on recipient, then you can use the `select * from privatemessages69 where sender = 19 or recipient = 19` and it will use and index on both. **if** you do not alter the table and thus do not add an index your code will **not** use an index on `recipient` because it is not the left-most part of a composite index, so **how is your code better than using a simple OR ?**

Comment: This appears to work very well, however when I add the ORDER BY id DESC back into the query, it slows down again. Explain shows its using filesort. is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: @Brian: filesort is not always a bad thing. It also depends on the size of the data that will be displayed (and needs ordering) and MySQL various memory (config) settings. And when you say "slow", what do you mean? How much time does the query need?

Comment: @soulmerge: You are (or I should say MySQL's online documentation is) wrong in that point. Two (or more) indexes on two (or more) separate fields can be used with OR, exactly as Brian's query. The version i checked (5.0.51) shows `type: index_merge` in the EXPLAIN.

Comment: This is a link to `index-merge`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: @ypercube Without the ORDER BY the query completes in about .03 seconds. With ORDER BY, it takes around 3-4 seconds.

Comment: ypercube mentions a good point, index_merge had been around for a few years now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to write an index where both columns have the first position. In your case adding:

```
CREATE INDEX `msgpanel_recp` ON `privatemessages69` (`recipient`,`id`)
```

Comment: This is using type:all when ORDER BY is removed from the query